# Как правильно прочитать данные. из Тега таблицы Python

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Мне нужно прочитать все строки из таблицы (их может быть миллион, а может и не быть вовсе) и записать в одну переменную типа String.

Пример таблицы ниже, помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

```
<table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td>Добрый день.<br>
Меня зовут Андрей.<br>
Более 6 лет я специализируюсь на красивых не стандартных слайд-шоу. <br>
Творческие люди оценят.)))<br>
Буду рад  выполнить Ваш заказ.<br>
Не стесняйтесь, обращайтесь.<br><br></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

html = """<table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td>Добрый день.<br>
Меня зовут Андрей.<br>
Более 6 лет я специализируюсь на красивых не стандартных слайд-шоу. <br>
Творческие люди оценят.)))<br>
Буду рад  выполнить Ваш заказ.<br>
Не стесняйтесь, обращайтесь.<br><br></td></tr></tbody></table>"""

soup = Soup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')

common_string = ''.join(table.strings)

print(common_string)
```

Вывод:

```latex
Добрый день.
Меня зовут Андрей.
Более 6 лет я специализируюсь на красивых не стандартных слайд-шоу. 
Творческие люди оценят.)))
Буду рад  выполнить Ваш заказ.
Не стесняйтесь, обращайтесь.
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как мало исходных данных, то вот приблизительное решение:

```
response = requests.get("url")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
tables = soup.find_all("table").find_all("td")
```

Получается список из td всех таблиц. Если нужна определенная таблица со страницы, то прописывается индекс

```
soup.find_all("table")[index].find_all("td")
```

Comment: Никогда не выстраивайте таких цепочек `soup.find_all("table").find_all("td")` всегда прверяйте как отработала каждая функция